# fluid Img component is shrinking when its under Link component

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

I am currently using gatsby for a project and when i put gatsby Img component inside Link component so that it's clickable, the image gets shrinked to its parent component(the link component). i know gatsby fluid Img stretches or shrinks to its parent's width but i want it to show as full image. i tried using `fixed` instead of `fluid` but it didn't work and it's even tried specifying width while querying.

[image: the code]

code

frontend part

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example or codesandbox? It seems a CSS issue so if you can provide the styles it would be awesome

Comment: css class i's from bootstrap. also when i give a width class to `Link` component, it works so i know it's stretching or shrinking to it's parent component. oh god, you're a genius. i just needed to remove the `className="w-100"` from `Img` and add it to the `Link` component. This solves the issue. Thanks a lot, ferran!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems clearly a CSS issue since your `<Link>` is shrinking to the text (`sssssssssss`) length.

Debug your `.thumbnail` class and the  component to see what's happening inside. For example, a CSS rules like the following will work but maybe don't fit your design specs:

```
.thumbnail{
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
}

.thumbnail a,
.thumbnail img {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Take a look at the resultant HTML output the adjust your selectors, since `gatsby-image` wraps the `<Img>` inside a nested structure, what may affect your CSS rules.

It seems that you are using Bootstrap (hence the `w-100`) so try adding it to the wrapper (`<Link>` component),